# What would be the pythonic way to represent an Either[ErrorT, ValueT] type with type annotations?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, type-annotation

I'm trying to annotate a python codebase, and I have a piece of code conceptually similar to this:

```
def could_fail_on_bad_input(value):
    if isinstance(value, ValidType):
        ...
        return transformed_value
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unsupported type")
```

I've checked Python's [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), [typing-extensions](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions), and [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), not to mention SO, but couldn't find a proper way to describe the return type of this function.

So far, the best idea I had is to represent the output type as `Union[NoReturn, ValidType]`, but I have a few issues with this. First, `NoReturn` means that the function doesn't return at all. Second, `NoReturn` feels too generic to me because I want to specify the exact error type this function can raise.

Note that I'm looking for a type hinting/annotation solution, not for a custom class to represent this.

Comment: It does answer the "Pythonic" part. Thank you!

Comment: btw `ValidType` is the same as `Union[NoReturn, ValidType]` because `NoReturn` is the bottom type. Perhaps you already know this and it's what you had issues with